# undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3Mat10deallocateEv

Tags: python, c++, opencv, extend

I've been trying to extend my python script with a C++ code. I was able to do that with the simple libraries of C++ (print "hello world"). I followed the tutorial available in the link below:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_further_extensions.htm

When I tried to add to my C++ code opencv libraries I encountered the following problem:
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kalman.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3Mat10deallocateEv

I searched for many solutions on the internet, and I found one common answer that didn't workout for me:
"I was able to solve this by going to /usr/lib64/pkgconfig and modified opencv.pc to explicitly have all libraries. I also had to move the plugins from /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10 to /usr/lib64/gstreamer-0.10"

Please note that I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit and I am planning to run my code later on on a raspberry pi model B running Raspbian OS.

Thank you.

NJ

Comment: Have you defined `cv::Mat::dealocate()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your shared library `kalman.so` with `ldd` like so:

```
 $ ldd kalman.so
```

And you will see that you are missing some libraries. That means that you have to provide some correct path to one of the libraries you use in your code at the linkage stage. something like

```
 $ ...the way you do linking ... -L path_to_the_missing_library
```

For more information, please, consult this [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/ldd.1.html).

Comment: Look for massages like "not found" or something like that

Comment: Make sure that you have `ldd` in your system and that you run this command in the folder containing `kalman.so `

Comment: got this as an output: linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffbec92000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb4c5c44000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb4c593e000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb4c5728000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb4c550a000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb4c5145000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb4c6150000)... What does it mean?

Comment: Please, provide the full list in your question.

Comment: And, please, show how you compile and link your library

Comment: 1- This is the full list

Comment: 2- The library is compiled with python: $ sudo python setup.py install

Comment: Setup.py: from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name='kalman', version='1.0',  \
      ext_modules=[Extension('kalman', ['kalman.cpp'])])

Comment: Oh, I see. I personally use `boost::python` and do not know exactly how you should link a specific library in your case. But the fact is, some library which contains `dealocate` method is not linked to your project. I guess, you should edit `ext_modules=...` block

Comment: I was searching yesterday for an alternative solution and I found boost.python... Can I pass values from the C++ program using opencv back to python? (using boost)

Comment: I'm not familiar with `opencv`, but in `boost`, of course, you can pass arbitrary values in both directions - from C++ to Python, and vice versa. However, it may require some coding.

Comment: Coding is the easy part :P Thank you for answering my questions!

Comment: Good luck! And happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same problem as you do, and at last I figured out that this is because I didn't add the linking library of opencv when compiling. Try to add the "opencv_core" or other related library when you compile the c++ source file.
Wish this to be helpful to you.